# How to get client addr from redis?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, redis, redistogo

I am testing Redis in heroku. I have simple flask app that can create the redis client and kill the client but ...

```
@app.route('/client-status')
def client_status():
    redis.client_setname("first")
    redis.client_kill('addr') #10.157.2.68:60097
    return "Success"
```

The question is how to get addr ? I know a way to get name `redis.client_getname()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the command **CLIENT LIST** http://redis.io/commands/client-list to get all the information about the client connections server, and then retrieve the address field

Comment: it returns one client connection per line, and each line is composed of fields (addr,id,db...) so you can access the addr field.

Comment: To make it easier to find the right client connection (to kill that is) from the list, you can also use [`CLIENT SETNAME`](http://redis.io/commands/client-setname) from the (to be killed) client - that would make pinpointing it a breeze :)